# Will the newly introduced 'Field Expansion' in graph api affect existing apps that depends on graph api to fetch data from Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, field

Facebook has introduced Field Expansion feature in Graph API to help developers to construct complex nested queries. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/field_expansion/

There is no doubt about the benefits this feature would give us. But what about the existing apps? Will this affect them or backward compatibility has been taken care?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm an engineer on the Platform team and worked on this feature. Everything is 100% backwards compatible; existing apps do not need to update.

Comment: How about pagination? "We'll no longer show the ‘previous’ or 'next' paging links when there's no new data." ... that sounds like a breaking change - unless it only applies to field expansion queries(?). p.s. Thanks for this awesome new functionality!

Comment: The previous behavior was: paginate until you don't get a previous/next link.
The current behavior is: paginate until you don't get a previous/next link.

The only difference is that for endpoints that have cursor based pagination the previous/next links will not be present on the last page. Endpoints that are not paginating via cursors will have one extra page with no results.

So this is not a breaking change either :)

Answer (score 1):

From the document you linked - 'This is meant as an advanced feature with no cost on the simplicity of the basic Graph API.'

I don't see any reason this feature of the API wouldn't be compatible with the basic usage that's already in place. It would have been announced as a breaking change otherwise

Answer (score -2):

My Application is affected. the `daily_active_users, weekly_active_users, monthly_active_users` on `graph.facebook.com/{APP_ID}` has been disappeared where did it go?

Comment: this is not answer... Ask your own question... ;-)